# Android Studio Generate Signed APK - Firmar APK

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

he creado una aplicación en Android y he generado un primer APK firmado a través de Android Studio y tengo un archivo .jks, una vez firmado el APK modifique algunas cosas del código y al querer volver a generar el APK firmado me salta el siguiente error que no se como solucionar y no puedo sacar un nuevo APK:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...
```

¿Alguien sabe que es lo que pasa? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

he conseguido resolver este problema y quería comentarlo por si a alguien más le sucede y no se vuelva loco, porque las traza que genera Android Studio para este caso no son claras y no indica cual es el problema de forma explícita.

Par mi APP yo he creado varios "Strings" en la carpeta values para realizar la internacionalización y se pueda ver en distintos idiomas, el problema es (aunque en alguna documentación de Android vi que no era necesario) todos deben ser iguales, es decir si pones un string "app_name", este debe aparecer en todos los strings (en alguna documentación de Android como he comentado indicaba que Android siempre busca en el string principal y si no lo encontraba en ese archivo, entonces se iba a el siguiente string pero que no era necesario que apareciera en todos los strings).

En definitiva, en modo debug no hay problema, pero en modo release para fimar el APK es necesario que todos los strings tenga los mismos campos, con esto se resuelve este problema concreto de firma APK.

Saludos.